# Dictionary as android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to work on android with eclipse , and my idea is to make a dictionary . the thought is that you are reading a file now you don't know a word you just have to click on that word it will redirect you to dictionary app " like word web " .

Now I don't know how to begin , on net also I was unable to find tutorials , can anyone tell me how to start with this .

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to be able to click on words in OTHER apps to launch your dictionary app, it is pretty much impossible. I suggest you start with an app that doesn't need to interact with other apps.

Good luck,

Barry

Comment: okk but I want to focus on the dictionary , if you are saying thats not possible then may be we can do like this I made a dictionary app where we print the word and gets its meaning like wordweb but in mobile . or redirect to a web page if not find there if thats the correct way .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Searchable Dictionary](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Database/SearchableDictionary.htm) as a starter and change the database with your own.